# Downgrading Php 5.4 to 5.3 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 10.04 server to 5.4 using these instructions: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-upgrade-install-php-540-under.html.

I'm experiencing some rather critical errors, and need to downgrade to 5.3.  I've found guides and scripts for later versions of Ubuntu, but the ones I have tried have thrown errors.

How can I downgrade?

Comment: The most likely route is that you will have to remove the packages and compile from source. This can sometimes be problematic with package dependencies.

Comment: This is a duplicate of an askubuntu question http://askubuntu.com/questions/116254/how-to-downgrade-from-php-5-4-to-5-3

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove php5`, then remove the php 5.4 ppa and `sudo apt-get update`, then install 5.3

Comment: You can remove PPA's using `ppa-purge`, which can be installed (and uninstalled afterwards) using `apt-get`

Comment: How do these answers affect other packages, such as curl and mcrypt?

Comment: @orion4567 `ppa-purge` will remove all packages from the specified PPA. If you installed the `mcrypt` extension from this PPA it will get removed. But you can install it again from the official ubuntu sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you need to remove the PPA after that is done, you can simply install the original packages from ubuntu again. There is a Tool called `ppa-purge` which does this exact thing. It's not installed by default so simply install it using:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then remove the PPA. **All packages you installed from this PPA get removed too!**

```sh
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Install the official packages from ubuntu again:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install php5 # ... other PHP 5.3 stuff
```

You may wan't to remove `ppa-purge` afterwards:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get remove ppa-purge
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the repo list as per the guide you mention. Remove your php by doing below

> apt-get remove php5
>
> apt-get purge php5

After which do an update of your pkg list

> apt-get update
>
> and now install the default version of php that comes with 10.04
>
> apt-get install php

Just a note, you can also force install a deb package that is available from ubuntu

> apt-get install somepackage=someversion